# Automorphism group of $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb{Z_n})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, semidirect-product, holomorph

I am reading about semidirect product in Dummit,Foots. I wonder the automorphism group of $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$, that is, $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_n^×$ with an operation $(a,b)*(c,d)=(a+bc,bd)$.

Generally, I hope to know about Holomorph of Holomorph, or the relation between $\operatorname{Hol}(G)$, $\operatorname{Hol}(K)$ and $\operatorname{Hol}(G×K)$. Is there a good theorem or any reference?

Comment: $a+bc$ here is not well-defined

Comment: Oh, there are typos. Edited!

Comment: And so more generally you define $Hol(G)$ as the semi-direct product of $G$ by $Aut(G)$ ?

Comment: The automorphism group of a direct prodcut can be quite complicated. See [ere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236571/) for example. As for ${\rm Hol}({\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z})$, I think it is complete when $n$ is odd, but has a small outer automorphism group when $n$ is even.

Comment: Max / Yes.  Derek Holt / Thank you. Can you let me know why are you think so?

Comment: @LWW, the proof of the completeness of $Hol(C_n)$ for odd $n$ is in the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863363/is-the-statement-that-operatornameaut-operatornameholz-n-cong-oper