# Prove or disprove: The direct sum of the multiplicative groups $U_n$ and $U_m$, $(m,n) = 1,$ is multiplicative group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm sorry if I am misunderstood. My native language is not English and this is my first time using this site.

I have home-work, to prove or to disprove the following statement:

> Let $m,n$ be natural numbers such that $g.c.d(m,n) = 1$. Then:
>
> The direct sum of the multiplicative groups $U_n$ and $U_m$ (where $U_n$ is the multiplicative group that contain the numbers that are relatively prime with $n$,), that is, the group $(U_n \times U_m)$ is a multiplicative group and isomorphic to $U_{mn}$

I've been trying to solve this for quite long time and I wasn't very successful with that.

I've noticed that $|U_{mn}| = |U_m||U_n|$ so with the obvious homomorphism $f(a) = (a \pmod m), a\pmod n)$ I just need to show that the function is either surjective or injective in order to show that the function is bijective and then it is a homomorphism.

I was trying to show that the kernel is empty but wasn't successful with that. I was also trying to show that for every element in the image there exist element in the domain that mapped to him but also I wasn't successful with that.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- [Product of two cyclic groups is cyclic iff their orders are co-prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5969/104041)
- [Automorphisms of a Cyclic Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3013033/104041)
- [Automorphism group of direct product of groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1236571/104041). Specifically, [Automorphism group of direct product of groups, proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3929476/104041)

The three fit together due to coprimality.

*NB:* The notation $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times=U_n$ is standard.

Comment: but n don't have to be a prime so Un don't have to be (Z/nZ). for example U10 = {1,3,7,9} but (Z/10Z)* = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: I don't follow, @hadadrefael. Where does it say $n$ is prime?

Comment: There's a difference between $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ and $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$, @hadadrefael.

Comment: Ok iv'e got it now thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the standard roadmap for that result:

- Use the Chinese remainder theorem to get $\Bbb Z/mn\Bbb Z \cong \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ as rings.
  An explicit isomorphism is exactly your $f$.
- Let $U_n=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$ and get $U_{mn} \cong U_{m} \times U_{n}$ from this general result:

> If $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings with unity, then $(A \times B)^\times = A^\times \times B^\times$, where $R^\times$ is the group of units of the ring $R$.