# Automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find the number of the subgroups whose order $5$ in the  $Aut(G)$. [Here $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{11}\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}   $]. Definitely, If the $G$ is a cyclic, $Aut(G)$ is $U(G)$. But, like the case I suggested, How can I find the isomorphic group?

Does $Aut(G \times H) \simeq Aut(G) \times Aut(H)$ ?  (Under the hypothesis, order of the G and H are relatively prime)

So back to the first question,  $Aut(G) \simeq Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3)\times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{11}\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}) $  What should I do next?

Is there any theorem realted with Aut( $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$)? Plus what if the $gcd(n,m) \not = 1$ ?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field ${\rm Aut}({\mathbb{Z}_{11}\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}})={\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_{11})$.

Comment: In general, $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ does not equal $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. They do, however, in the special case in which $G$ and $H$ are both abelian of relatively prime orders. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236571/automorphism-group-of-direct-product-of-groups)

Comment: What concepts are you expected to use? Do you know Sylow's theorems? Do you know that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ (this can be proved easily regardless). Do you know how to compute the order of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$? This question is not "that hard" if you know the right theorems,but not much context is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go ahead and solve your particular example, and note that the tools are presented in the comments.

Since $(3,121)=1$, we have that  $\rm {Aut}(\mathbb Z_3×\mathbb Z_{11}×\mathbb Z_{11})\cong\rm {Aut}(\mathbb Z_3)×\rm {Aut}(\mathbb Z_{11}×\mathbb Z_{11}) $.

And this will be $\mathbb Z_2×\rm {GL_2 (\mathbb Z_{11})} $.